# Google plus sharing in my android application is posting an advertisement

Tags: android

When I share text on Google plus an advertisement is also getting posted with the text itself. How to stop posting advertisement on sharing text.I am using code below.

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText(shareText)
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
    .getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, what you expect and what the actual output is?

Comment: Yes sure, my code is working fine, the text is shared successfully but with that text an advertisement for Google plus platform is also showing.I don't want that advertisement to come along with the text.

Comment: The content is populated by [`setContentUrl`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html#setContentUrl(android.net.Uri)). Remove that part.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was just stuck at this and was not able to find anything related to it.And thanx again for your quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is populated by [`setContentUrl`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html#setContentUrl(android.net.Uri)). Remove that part.